# Is it possible to change mobile settings in ionic application?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

Hi i'm writing application using ionic 3 + cordova. Is it possible to change some android settings(like change language, date(time), sound etc) inside my application?Cordova-open-native-settings not suitable. Ask permissions not a problem

Comment: Why is it not suitable `Cordova-open-native-settings`?

Comment: @Sampath I want to change settings by pressing some buttons in application